# What adjective would mean "both former and still present", but not "original"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The pop group “Kitties'” original lineup went as follows: Linda, Mary and Amanda. However, Amanda soon left the group and Jenny replaced her.

They decided that their first performance in a new lineup would be like this: Linda and Mary would sing first and then, 5 minutes later, Jenny would join them.

Imagine you are watching that performance and you don't know the singers' names, but you do know them by their faces and you are aware of their recent lineup change.

However, YOU ARE NOT AWARE OF WHAT THEIR ORIGINAL LINEUP WAS. Simply put, you only saw Linda, Mary and Amanda performing together several times before, but you don't know whether
those three have been in the group from the very beginning or they have also replaced some other members who went before them.

Now imagine, you are writing a report about that performance:

> The two ***previous-lineup*** singers
>   were singing first. Then, about 5
>   minutes later, the new member of their
>   group joined them. It was really a
>   nice performance.

Here is my question: is there any single adjective in English that I could substitute for "***previous-lineup***" in my quote above?

I tried using just "*previous*", but that would seem to mean that those two singers are now gone, too (along with Amanda).

The adjective "*former*" seems to bring the same meaning.

The word "*original*" would not work either due to the reason I have already stated above.

Perhaps, "*old*" would fit the bill, but the problem is... the girls are quite young and you don't want to describe them using this word as even if you don't mean to imply their age that could still cause some undesirable and sensitive associations.

So, what adjective you would use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *existing* is probably the best word. It indicate both past and present time.

Comment: What? The other singer did not exist before? That sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

- established
- vintage
- classic
- traditional
- experienced
- customary
- familiar

Alternatively you can refer to them as "singers" and the new singer gets the clarification:

- new / newest
- recently added / most recent

And there is always the option of avoiding the problem altogether:

> [name], [name] and [name] were singing first. Then, about 5 minutes later, the new member of their group joined them.

Answer (score 0):

I think *longtime member* would fit the bill.